# nuxt with leaflet: "window is not defined" even when using the component inside ClientOnly

Tags: leaflet, nuxtjs3

### Description

I'm using nuxt@^3.8.2 and leaflet@^1.9.4 for my project. I'm trying to render a map within the `ClientOnly` component provided by nuxt. But I'm still getting the `window is not defined` error. If I use the same code in the regular Vue project, it works fine. I've tried using nuxt module like `nuxt3-leaflet`, and the code works properly, but it seems to inject the whole leaflet inside every page, which makes the app heavy in those pages where maps are not needed. Can anybody guide me on how to get through this issue? Thanks in advance.

### Parent Component

```js
            <v-card class="rent__map">
                <RentMap />
            </v-card>
```

### Map Component

```js
<template>
    <ClientOnly fallback-tag="div">
        <template #fallback>
            <div class="d-flex justify-center align-center" style="height: 100%;">
                <v-progress-circular indeterminate color="primary" />
            </div>
        </template>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </ClientOnly>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import L from 'leaflet';
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

const zoom = ref(12);
const center = ref([27.700769, 85.300140]);
const map = ref<LMap | null>(null);
const tile = {
    url: "https://{s}.google.com/vt?lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}",
    attribution: "Google",
    layerType: "base",
    name: "OpenStreetMap",
    subDomains: ['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
};

onMounted(() => {
    map.value = L.map('map').setView(center.value, zoom.value);
    L.tileLayer(tile.url, {
        attribution: tile.attribution,
        layerType: tile.layerType,
        name: tile.name,
        subdomains: tile.subDomains
    }).addTo(map.value);
});
</script>
```

### Error

```
500
window is not defined

at ./node_modules/.pnpm/leaflet@1.9.4/node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js:7:66
at Object. (./node_modules/.pnpm/leaflet@1.9.4/node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js:10:3)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
at cjsLoader (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:284:17)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:234:7)
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:217:25)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ClientOnly` component does not work in your Map component. Once you import `leaflet`, the code is executed on server side.

Here are 3 solutions:

##### 1.Wrap the component from parent

This will prevent importing `leaflet` on sever side

```js
<v-card class="rent__map">
  <ClientOnly>
    <RentMap />
  </ClientOnly>
</v-card>
```

##### 2.Turn off SSR

turn off globally:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: false
})
```

or turn off SSR for the page depending on `leaflet` (Hybrid rendering):

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  routeRules: {
    // pages containing leaflet renders only on client-side
    '/map/**': { ssr: false },
  }
})
```

##### 3.Dynamic import

Only import `leaflet` after mounted

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';

const zoom = ref(12);
const center = ref([27.700769, 85.30014]);
const map = ref<LMap | null>(null);
const tile = {
  url: 'https://{s}.google.com/vt?lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',
  attribution: 'Google',
  layerType: 'base',
  name: 'OpenStreetMap',
  subDomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3'],
};

onMounted(async () => {
  const L = (await import('leaflet')).default;
  map.value = L.map('map').setView(center.value, zoom.value);
  L.tileLayer(tile.url, {
    attribution: tile.attribution,
    layerType: tile.layerType,
    name: tile.name,
    subdomains: tile.subDomains,
  }).addTo(map.value);
});
</script>
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-lesosh

Comment: The first solution did not work. I do not know why. I had tried it before too. The second is not what I want, so I have not tried it yet. But the third solution is great. That is just what I want. Thank you.